# How can I tell whether the text I receive from a network/read from a file uses a given encoding?

Tags: java, character-encoding

I have a file, or I read from a socket; the data I read is supposed to be text encoded with a given character coding.

But even if I specify a coding and it turns out to be wrong in the end, the operation succeeds; instead of an exception of any sort, I get a lot of `�` in my text :/

Is there a way I can trigger a failure instead?

Comment: I was surprised that you could work this out, until I realised you had. Good answer.

Answer (score 5):

Yes there is.

First, some information: what is that pesky `�` character, really? Well, it is [Unicode's "replacement character", code point U+FFFD](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm).

Now, why do you get this? In order to explain this, we need to delve a little deeper into what happens...

First, a "formal" definition: a *character coding* is a process which defines a bijection between a stream of bytes and a stream of characters; as it is a bijection, it means that two operations are defined: encoding (turning a stream of characters into a stream of bytes) and decoding (turning a stream of bytes into a stream of characters).

In Java, a character coding is encompassed in a [`Charset`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html); you can obtain an encoder using [`Charset.newEncoder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newEncoder--), and a decoder using [`Charset.newDecoder()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/Charset.html#newDecoder--).

And of course, it can happen that in the decoding process, which is what is of interest here, a certain sequence of bytes turns out to be malformed, in which case the `CharsetDecoder` must decide what to do... And this behavior depends on [`CodingErrorAction`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CodingErrorAction.html), which has three values:

- `REPLACE` (**the default!!**): replace any unmappable sequence with Unicode's replacement character!
- `IGNORE`: scrap all unmappable sequences, don't output anything;
- `REPORT`: throw an exception on an unmappable sequence...

Now, what we want in order to detect malformed inputs and throw an error is to `REPORT` them!

So, how do we do this given an `InputStream`? The solution is to use an `InputStreamReader`; [it has a constructor allowing you to specify a `CharsetDecoder` as an argument](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/InputStreamReader.html#InputStreamReader-java.io.InputStream-java.nio.charset.CharsetDecoder-). All you have to do is to create your decoder!

For instance, if you want to ensure correct UTF-8, you would do this:

```
final CharsetDecoder decoder = StandardCharsets.UTF_8
    .newDecoder().onMalformedInput(CodingErrorAction.REPORT);

try (
    final InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(in, decoder);
) {
    // read from the reader here
}
```

The exception you want to catch here is a [`CharacterCodingException`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/charset/CharacterCodingException.html). Note that it inherits `IOException`, so you want to:

```
try (
    ...
) {
    ...
} catch (CharacterCodingException e) {
    ...
} catch (IOException e) {
    ...
}
```